# IOS 10.2.1 Backup and restore backup

Tags: backup, restore

Sync Ipads with Itunes on Computer : it backs up then when I look at Summary it tells me this ipad has never been backed up to this computer? I have done this forever.
So I then decided to go to Files : Devices : Restore Backup, which I do regularly and iPad backups up automatically when syncing anyway, and Backup device is highlighted and Restore Backup is greyed out so I cant do this either? W
hat is happening.  My last 2 weeks have been a nightmare upgrading to IOS 10 and now again IOS 10.2.1.  I am working with a bank of 25 iPads so to loads seperately onto each iPad - my last resort which I have just started is really the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Sync Ipads with Itunes on Computer : it backs up then when I look at Summary it tells me this ipad has never been backed up to this computer?

iTunes does not automatically back up every time you sync, so maybe it didn't do a backup just then? If you press the button to make a backup, does it backup successfully and change the last backup date?

An article I wrote awhile ago about syncing vs backing up, for reference:
https://deciphertools.com/blog/2015_01_27_itunes_sync_vs_backup_ensure_data/

Comment: The message is still there and on every ipad.... I had 25 ipads and they have always backed up automatically to my computer, it is set on my system to do this.  This is the first time in the 6 years i have used ipads I have had a problem.  I update and resync my ipads every week ie over 3000 times x 25 ipads .  So i dont think  that is the answer